# Laravel Eloquent: Polymorphic One-to-...well, it depends

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, polymorphism, eloquent

I have 3 models (Product, Category, Image). A product can have multiple images, and a category should have one image. This sounds like polymorphic relations to me, but I'm just not sure if the way I want it set up will actually work.

Can I do one-to-many on the Product and one-to-one **to the same polymorphic field** on the Category? Or do I need to make both into one-to-many relationships, and use `->first()` every time I want a category image?

I'm not 100% au fait with polymorphic relationships and my head's swimming a bit from trying to work out how I need to set up the 3 models, so any kind of explanations would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: I actually had this same issue this week. For now I'm doing ->first() on the category image like you suggest. I couldnt find a better solution - but I'm interested if someone else does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just works, unless I misunderstand your intentions..

```
// Image model
public function imageable()
{
   return $this->morphTo();
}

---

// Product model
public function images()
{
   return $this->morphMany('Image', 'imageable');
}
// you can have this one too (default image for example)
public function image()
{
   return $this->morphOne('Image', 'imageable');
}

---

// Category model
public function image()
{
   return $this->morphOne('Image', 'imageable');
}

---
// Usage:

$product = Product::first();
$product->image; // first Image model
$product->images; // Collection of Image models

$category = Category::first();
$category->image; // the only Image model
```